# When install the "@sencha/ext-web-components" in vue application this error occour?

Tags: vue.js, npm, extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm adding this `"@sencha/ext-web-components"` package in to package.json and run `npm install`. This error occour?

[image: E]

Comment: I think you can not install it, because there is not package with that name, check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=sencha%2Fext-web-components

Comment: But its give in the sencha doc: https://docs.sencha.com/extwebcomponents/7.0.0/guides/getting_started_vue.html

Comment: I think its in their internal npm package, check this: https://docs.sencha.com/extwebcomponents/7.0.0/guides/using_npm/npm_packages.html